# Mysql - оптимизация select *

Tags: mysql, sql

Во всех гайдах предупреждают не использовать выборки select * по причине лишних нагрузок.

Цитата из офф руководства

Вместо использования 'SELECT *' всегда указывайте столбцы в предложении SELECT, чтобы повысить производительность MySQL. Поскольку ненужные столбцы создают дополнительную нагрузку на базу данных, замедляя ее работу, а также весь системный процесс.

Листая офф доки оптимизации наткнулся на момент "если таблица содержит строковые столбцы, но многие запросы не извлекают эти столбцы, рассмотрите их вынесение в отдельную таблицу и вызов соединения внешнего ключа по мере необходимости. Извлекая любое значение строки, mysql считывает блок данных со всей строкой всех столбцов, а возможно и другие соседние строки. Так вы сократите ввод-вывод и использование памяти к общим запросам. Сохранение каждой строки небольшой, с использованием только наиболее часто используемых столбцов позволяет большему количеству строк поместиться в каждый блок данных"

О чем речь? О ситуациях с hdd? О размере таблицы распределения 1-2-4-8-16-32kb любого диска?

Comment: Ну тут 2 совершенно не связанные рекомендации. указание только нужных столбцов в select разгружает предварительное хранение результата и отдачу его по сети клиенту. А по поводу длинных редко используемых столбцов речь про дисковый ввод-вывод. и по моему в приведенной вами выдержке все очень точно написано. Суть в том, что чем больше длина записи тем больше читать с диска придется для получения этой и соседних записей

Comment: Тут речь не только о блоках данных при чтении с диска. БД тоже хранит данные таблиц блоками, своими, внутренними. Но дальше уже детали реализации конкретной базы начинаются, база может строки где-то отдельно от остальных данных таблицы хранить, а может и нет. Это надо в детали вдаваться. Но в общем случае да, лучше разделить те данные, которые нужны часто, и те, которые нужны редко, в отдельные таблицы. Особенно если это строки и другие объёмные данные.